# Can "degringolade of something" mean a period of downfall in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> It is a phase of human life that may lead, as I am trying to show,
> either to a new way of life for our species or else to a longer or
> briefer dégringolade of violence, misery, destruction, death and the
> extinction of mankind.

*The new world order by H.G. Wells*

I wan to understand the word degringolade in this context. According to [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d%C3%A9gringolade) the word is synonym with "downfall":

> a rapid decline or deterioration (as in strength, position, or condition) : downfall

But I get confused.

Does the author means: the downfall of violence? like there will be no violence?
Or a period of downfall that there is violence and misery in it?

Comment: A downfall **composed** of violence, misery, etc. Dégringolade is a rarely used French loan word.

Comment: I agree with MichaelHarvey and then some, meaning I'd say it's very, very, very, very rarely used, so rarely that between 2011 and 2019, according to Google Ngram, it appeared in only 11 books published in English, not including dictionaries. So rare is this word in English, you'd be better off asking a French speaker how to use it than an English speaker, because if my dictionary's definition of "dégringolade" is any indication, it'd appear even H. G. Wells didn't quite know how to use this French loanword properly, making anyone being able to answer your question a bit of a sticky wicket.

Comment: What those guys said. Any non-native speaker who looks up ["dégringolade"](https://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/degringolade#:~:text=A%20degringolade%20is%20simply%20a,for%20which%20see%20Word%20History).) in a dictionary (English ***or*** French) will understand the meaning far better than almost all Anglophones (who will mostly never have encountered it at all, or possibly just *once* in HG Wells usage as cited).

Comment: I wonder if the word was italicized in the text? Often, words like that are. It's pretty common in French, by the way. A better translation here is the unleashing of a, b and c.

Comment: @Lambie it was not italicized in the text